# How can I use parameters in a messages.properties file?

Tags: java

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5600055/456218), it points out, It's possible to have something like:

```
message.myMessage = This message is for {0} in {1}
```

But I don't know how to pass parameter to it

```java
MESSAGES.getString("message.myMessage", "foor", "bar")
```

but unfortunately getString can't know take other parameters
Any idea?

Comment: What's the type of MESSAGES?

Comment: @JBNizet it's ResourceBundle

Answer (score 33):

I'm guessing you're thinking of [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)?  If so, it's just this:

```
String s = MessageFormat.format("This message is for {0} in {1}", "foo", "bar");
```

Or from properties:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("messages.myMessage", "This message is for {0} in {1}");
String s = MessageFormat.format(
    p.getProperty("messages.myMessage"), "foo", "bar");
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, Does `ResourceBundle` have the getProperty methods

Comment: `private static final Properties MESSAGES = new Properties().load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("rawcode.gui.messages"));`

Answer (score 13):

Try out this one:

```java
String message = "This message is for {0} in {1}.";
String result = MessageFormat.format(message, "me", "the next morning");
System.out.println(result);
```

(`java.text.MessageFormat;`)

Or in JSF:

```html
<h:outputFormat value="This message is for {0} in {1}.">
    <f:param value="me">
    <f:param value="the next morning">
</h:outputFormat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a String Array.

```
String[] params = new String[2]; 
params[0] = "This is your text including parameters";
params[1] = "This is your second text including parameters";
```

If you are using JSF, pass Array to the text this way from your backing bean as a warning text :

```
JsfUtil.addWarn("A_MSG_TITLE_IN_PROPERTIES_FILE", params);
```

And insert this line to your local properties file:

```
A_MSG_TITLE_IN_PROPERTIES_FILE = Hello {0} and {1}
```

So, output will be :

*Hello This is your text including parameters and This is your second text including parameters*